# Test React function components promises behaviour with Jest,

Tags: reactjs, jestjs, asynctest

I have a React function component.
I pass a function to the component as a prop, that returns a promise.
I use that function on an `onClick` event and once the promise is resolved, I change the state of the component.
Something like:

```js
import React, { useState } from 'react';

function myComponent({ aPromiseReturningFunction }) {
    const [myState, setState] = useState('12');
    const clickHandler = () => {
      aPromiseReturningFunction().then(() => { setState('123') })
    };

    return <div onClick={ clickHandler }>{myState}</div>
}
```

Inside my test:

```js
const myFunc = jest.fn(() => Promise.resolve(true));
const componentWrapper = shallow(<myComponent aPromiseReturningFunction={ myFunc }/>);
componentWrapper.simulate('click');
expect(componentWrapper.text()).toEqual('123');
```

Obviously the above fails, but I have not found anything that would explain how to properly test the above. Of course If I change the state outside the promise, the test passes.

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 3):

Since `click` is updating the state after a promise aka asynchronously, I would use [act](https://reactjs.org/docs/test-utils.html#act)

```
import { act } from 'react-dom/test-utils'; // other testing libraries have similar methods that test async events

const myFunc = jest.fn(() => Promise.resolve(true));

it('updates text after onclick', () => {
  const componentWrapper = shallow(<myComponent aPromiseReturningFunction={ myFunc }/>);
  act(() => {
    componentWrapper.simulate('click');
  });

  expect(componentWrapper.text()).toEqual('123');
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to [alextrastero](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2902063/alextrastero), I managed to come to a solution eventually.

What is missing from alextrastero's answer is that we should enclose the `act()` inside async/await like:

```js
import { act } from 'react-dom/test-utils'; // other testing libraries have similar methods that test async events

const myFunc = jest.fn(() => Promise.resolve(true));

it('updates text after onclick', async () => {
  const componentWrapper = shallow(<myComponent aPromiseReturningFunction={ myFunc }/>);
  await act(() => {
    componentWrapper.simulate('click');
  });

  expect(componentWrapper.text()).toEqual('123');
});
```

And in order for that to work, I also needed to use the `regenerator-runtime/runtime` package.